# I have a code in PHP how do this in python cURL

Tags: php, python, curl

I have some problem, one person have a ubuntu server without php, and this person don't want install php on this server, I need upload file usuing cURL or python for them, but I know only how do this in php, I dont have any basic steps with python :(. Someone can help me with this bottom my code with php. I trying some like this

```
Python

with open('plik.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    r = requests.post(https://somelink/companies, data=csv_file)
```

cURL

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/csv" --request POST --data-binary "@test.csv" https://somelink/companies
```

What I'm doing wrong

```
$url = 'https://somelink/companies';

$params = array(
    'key' => '8e7bdd23qa1d06b493152ea37cd4ah39',
    'csv' => file_get_contents('test.csv'),
); 

$query = http_build_query($params);

$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n".
                    "User-Agent: uploader_pmg_companies\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => $query,
            ),
        ));

$result = file_get_contents($url, $flags = null, $ctx);
```

Comment: In your cURL attempt you are sending different values for some headers, other headers are completely missing – and you are not even sending the right data. If you actually understand what your PHP code does - then go figure out what the cURL equivalents are by reading the man page.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ok I wrote in python some like this
```

> import requests
>
> ```
> url = "https://somelink/companies"
> files = {'file': open('plik.csv', 'rb')}
> payload = {'key': '8e7bdd23qa1d06b493152ea37cd4ah39', 'csv': files}
> headers = {'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'User-Agent: uploader_pmg_companies'}
> r = requests.post(url, params=payload, files=files)
> print r.url
> print (r.text)
> ```

```
And server answer {"file_csv_content":"file...","status":success"}

So this works?
```